# Playing Encrypted Videos using AVPlayer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

So, I'm trying to play an encrypted video using AVplayer, and nothing shows up in the player.

So my progress towards that project is as follows:

1.Implemented an `AVPlayer` that will have an `UIView` which is going to play the AV content (this is working fine for playing non encrypted files.)

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:fileURL options:nil]; //local file url with custom scheme         
AVAssetResourceLoader *loader = [asset resourceLoader];
[loader setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
[self.playerView setPlayer:self.player];
```

From the above code, I know that my following resource loader method is being called:

2.Implemented the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` protocol, and I've implemented the resource loader method as follows.

```
- (BOOL) resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest 
{
    NSURLRequest* request = loadingRequest.request;
    AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest* dataRequest = loadingRequest.dataRequest;
    AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest* contentRequest = loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest;
    NSMutableData *data;
    //handle content request
    if (contentRequest)
    {
        contentRequest.contentType = @"mov";
        contentRequest.contentLength = movieFileLengthInBytes
        contentRequest.byteRangeAccessSupported = YES;
    }
    if (dataRequest)
    {
        DecryptedStream* readStream = [FS getReadStream:filename error:nil];
        if (readStream)
        {
            while ([readStream hasBytesAvailable])
            {
                NSInteger nRead;
                uint8_t buffer[kBufferReadSize];
                nRead = [readStream read:buffer maxLength:kBufferReadSize];
                NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
                [data appendBytes:buffer length:nRead];
                [dataRequest respondWithData:data];
            }
        }
        [loadingRequest finishLoading];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Based on the above code, and from other further reading in apple documents for resourceloader:

> During loading, the resource loader object may be asked to assist in
> the loading of a resource. For example, a resource that requires
> decryption might result in the resource loader being asked to provide
> the appropriate decryption keys. You can assign a delegate object to
> the resource loader object and use your delegate to intercept these
> requests and provide an appropriate response

which is basically what I'm doing. However, I can't get my video to play. I made sure data that I've decrypted is correct (i.e, I can write it to a tmp file and can play my mov).

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your resource loader method and stepped through it to see what values are being set, especially for `data`?

Comment: yep, verified that it is the correct data by writing it to a temp file, and I can play my file.

Comment: You might want to check out the sample app [AVARLDelegateDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc1791/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)

Comment: A-Live, I've been to this one before and I believe that the sequence of operation is pretty much the same, they are using a a bunch of dispatch queues which I'm not.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nop, I haven't had the chance to look at it back.

Answer (score 3):

I am also stuck on this task for several day. It is not difficult, but there isn't enough information (or clearly information) of how to use `AVAssetResourceLoader` and `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`. Here is something I get when doing this task:

1. If you are loading a local video file, you must provide a custom scheme for your `fileURL` in order to be able to use `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`.

   ```
   let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(URL: fileURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
   urlComponents?.scheme = "enc"
   let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: urlComponents!.URL!, options: nil)
   ```

   Simple use `let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: fileURL, options: nil)` won't trigger any of `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`
2. In use of `resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest` you must provide the `contentInformationRequest` for `loadingRequest`. You can find the list of video format [AV Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Format_UTIs). And another thing is `contentLength`. It must be set to the size of the decrypted file, not the file you are using to decrypt.
3. The `loadingRequest` can request overlap data or request same data many times. So that you can't simply decode and paste data to the `dataRequest`. You will need to have another buffer for decoding data. And in `resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest`, check if you have enough data to return or you need to decode more. When you decode for more data, you can clean up previous buffer to keep memory low but remember to copy any unused data in the previous buffer.

And, I suggest you try to play a non-encrypted file first. Make sure your method to loading data for `loadingRequest` works properly before jumping into encrypted file. At the end you will find it is very fun and interesting in doing task like this. Happy coding :)

Comment: hi Sahara, thank you for your comment. Do you have a link of your code repository?

Comment: I also need that :)

Comment: @sahara108 I have tried what you have suggested except point 3 since I am first trying with a small non-encrypted file. Still I am not able to play the video. My code isa same as in the question with your first two suggestion added. Could you help me solve it

Comment: @prabhu can you share ur code. I will take a look and see if I can help.

Answer (score 1):

in the line

```
contentRequest.contentType = @"mov";
```

you have to set valid UTI of decrypted content like

```
contentRequest.contentType = @"public.mpeg-4";
```